# Filter row by first and last condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, rows

I would like to remove all rows before a specific factor (in this case the first Running in Run column) and all rows after the last specific case (in this case also Running in Run Column).

data <- tribble(
~Date, ~Time, ~Run,
"17/04/12", "00:10:00", "Stop",
"17/04/12", "00:19:00", "Stop",
"17/04/12", "00:25:00", "Running",
"17/04/12", "00:29:00", "Running",
"17/04/12", "00:25:00", "Stop",
"17/04/12", "00:29:00", "Running",
"17/04/12", "00:30:00", "Running",
"18/04/12", "00:10:00", "Stop",
"18/04/12", "00:14:00", "Running",
"18/04/12", "00:20:00", "Stop"
"18/04/12", "00:24:00", "Stop"
"18/04/12", "00:26:00", "Stop"
)

| Date | Time | Run |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17/04/12 | 00:10:00 |  |
| 17/04/12 | 00:19:00 |  |
| 17/04/12 | 00:25:00 | Running |
| 17/04/12 | 00:29:00 | Running |
| 17/04/12 | 00:25:00 | Stop |
| 17/04/12 | 00:29:00 | Running |
| 17/04/12 | 00:30:00 | Running |
| 18/04/12 | 00:10:00 | Stop |
| 18/04/12 | 00:14:00 | Running |
| 18/04/12 | 00:20:00 | Stop |
| 18/04/12 | 00:24:00 | Stop |
| 18/04/12 | 00:26:00 | Stop |

Result:

| Date | Time | Run |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17/04/12 | 00:25:00 | Running |
| 17/04/12 | 00:29:00 | Running |
| 17/04/12 | 00:25:00 | Stop |
| 17/04/12 | 00:29:00 | Running |
| 17/04/12 | 00:30:00 | Running |
| 18/04/12 | 00:10:00 | Stop |
| 18/04/12 | 00:14:00 | Running |

Comment: Could you share an example dataset with us using `dput` please

Comment: Yes. Here:library(tidyverse); data <- tribble(
  ~Date, ~Time, ~Run,
  "17/04/12", "00:10:00", "Stop",
  "17/04/12", "00:19:00", "Stop",
  "17/04/12", "00:25:00", "Running",
  "17/04/12", "00:29:00", "Running",
  "17/04/12", "00:25:00", "Stop",
  "17/04/12", "00:29:00", "Running",
  "17/04/12", "00:30:00", "Running",
  "18/04/12", "00:10:00", "Stop",
  "18/04/12", "00:14:00", "Running",
  "18/04/12", "00:20:00", "Stop"
)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(Run %in% c("Running", "Stop")) %>% 
  slice(1:max(which(Run == "Running")))
```

This gives us:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  Date     Time     Run    
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>  
1 17/04/12 00:25:00 Running
2 17/04/12 00:29:00 Running
3 17/04/12 00:25:00 Stop   
4 17/04/12 00:29:00 Running
5 17/04/12 00:30:00 Running
6 18/04/12 00:10:00 Stop   
7 18/04/12 00:14:00 Running
```

Answer (score 2):

Along your data analysis journey, you will face this problem often.
If you want to or will have to add more logical checks, you can introduce variables on which you filter. In your case we can simply count the occurrences of Running and Stop. We then use the additional columns to filter your data frame.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
 mutate(  RunCounts = cumsum(Run == "Running")
       , StopCounts = cumsum(Run == "Stop")
       ) %>% 
 filter(RunCounts >= 1 & StopCounts < max(StopCounts))
```

This yields:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 5
  Date     Time     Run     RunCounts StopCounts
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>       <int>      <int>
1 17/04/12 00:25:00 Running         1          2
2 17/04/12 00:29:00 Running         2          2
3 17/04/12 00:25:00 Stop            2          3
4 17/04/12 00:29:00 Running         3          3
5 17/04/12 00:30:00 Running         4          3
6 18/04/12 00:10:00 Stop            4          4
7 18/04/12 00:14:00 Running         5          4
```

You can remove the introduced columns by selecting the ones you are interested in:

```
data %>% mutate(RunCounts = cumsum(Run == "Running"), StopCounts = cumsum(Run == "Stop")) %>% filter(RunCounts >= 1 & StopCounts < max(StopCounts)) %>% select(Date, Time, Run)
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  Date     Time     Run    
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>  
1 17/04/12 00:25:00 Running
2 17/04/12 00:29:00 Running
3 17/04/12 00:25:00 Stop   
4 17/04/12 00:29:00 Running
5 17/04/12 00:30:00 Running
6 18/04/12 00:10:00 Stop   
7 18/04/12 00:14:00 Running
```

Comment: Nice. But in this example, if there are many Stop after the last Running, using your script, there is no possibility to remove the additional stop. I edited the example.

Comment: You can construct many complex logical conditions. Obviously this depends on your dataset and problem case at hand. So what you are looking for is a condition: `max StopCounts and previous Run == "Running"`. You can look for previous/next in dplyr with `lead()`/`lag()`. If you need to combine multiple and possibly more complex logical conditions, `case_when()` is your friend.